# Python HIDAPI troubleshooting: open() failures

Tags: python-2.7, osx-yosemite, barcode-scanner, hid

OS X \ Python 2.7.15 is outfitted with a USB scanner:

```
user$ lsusb | grep Metrologic
Bus 250 Device 005: ID 0c2e:9a6c 0c2e Metrologic Scanner
```

[The python statement that attempts to open the HID device:](https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi/blob/master/try.py)

```
h.open(0x0c2e, 0x9a6c)  # METROLOGIC VendorID/ProductID
```

produces an error message:

```
user$ python2 test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 46, in <module>
    h.open(0x0c2e, 0x9a6c)  # METROLOGIC VendorID/ProductID
  File "hid.pyx", line 66, in hid.device.open
IOError: open failed
```

HID devices are enumerated with the [Python HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/hidapi/doxygen/html/group__API.html):

```
### enumerate USB devices
for d in hid.enumerate():
    keys = list(d.keys())
    keys.sort()
    for key in keys:
        print("%s : %s" % (key, d[key]))
    print()
```

and returns the target HID device info:

```
                interface_number : -1
                manufacturer_string : Metrologic
                path : IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/EHC2@1A,7/EHC2@fa000000/PRT1@fa100000/IOUSBHostDevice@fa100000/AppleUSB20InternalHub@fa100000/PRT3@fa130000/Metrologic Scanner@fa130000/IOUSBHostInterface@0/IOUSBHostHIDDevice@fa130000,0
                vendor_id : 3118     
                product_id : 39532
                product_string : Metrologic Scanner
                release_number : 21574
                serial_number : 
                usage : 6
                usage_page : 1
```

Attempts to open the HID device with decimal (instead of hexadecimal) arguments:

```
h.open(3118,39532)      # METROLOGIC VendorID/ProductID
```

also fail:

```
user$ python2 test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 47, in <module>
    h.open(3118,39532)      # METROLOGIC VendorID/ProductID
  File "hid.pyx", line 66, in hid.device.open
IOError: open failed
```

## QUESTIONS

1. Is there enough information here to diagnose or is there another test to be performed to diagnose the failure?
2. Are the h.open() arguments incorrect?
3. What are the next steps / strategy to diagnose & correct?

Any diagnostic questions are appreciated and will responses will be update to the original posting.

Answer (score 2):

I also got same problem, but after googling, found this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pywws/Gp3kGbRRFXA).
Switching to root user solved my problem. Maybe you did not have enough permission.

Comment: I forgot how I resolved this problem (the scanner works), however, my script always executes the python script as root to ensure permissions are not an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

use try to type sudo defore python2 test5.py
like that : 
user$sudo python2 test5.py

Comment: This doesn't add anything new.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

Apparently you need to add a udev rule

In `/etc/udev/rules/99-my-device.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04d8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Note: you may want to update the VID number to match your case.

Comment: Please consider adding any reference and thought process you went through to augment your answer (below your current posting).

Comment: Sorry, your solution was to run as root.... that was a no-go for me.
With adding such a dev-rule you can run the program with normal user credits.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the safest option for Linux users: https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi#udev-rules